# Scheduling background jobs without duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, delayed-job

We have rails app that synchronizes with another app. It's happening in the background. Basically, every time this job just synchronizes all the data so at the moment it is really slow and we are looking for speeding the process up by using parallelism.

Basically this looks like this at the moment:

```
accounts.each { |a| sync_account(a) }
```

And we want it to look like this:

```
accounts.each { |a| SyncAccountJob.perform_later(a) }
```

To be precise, we want to use background queues for this. For starters, we wanna use one job per account (we have many accounts that need sync). The problem here is how do we prevent our queue from getting the same job multiple times?

For example, if we schedule jobs every hour sometimes when some account is not yet synchronized the new job will be scheduled (sorry for my english).

What would you do?

We think we should just keep an ID of created job in accounts table and just check if the job doesn't exist before scheduling it again.

The other questions is what system do we use: delayed_job (already in use by mailers) or sidekiq?

Another problem: "zombie" jobs. For example, let's say I scheduled some job (delayed_job) and worker started to process it. Now it is locked. And then the server crashes so job is still locked but nothing is processing it. Does delayed_job/sidekiq resolve this issue on its own or should I write some cleaner?

I would appreciate any comments or stories on the topic.

Comment: Sidekiq Enterprise has "unique jobs" feature.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks, I will look into it

Answer (score 2):

> if we schedule jobs every hour

You can use [sidekiq-cron](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron) in this case. It will make sure that no same jobs will run at the same time.
Of course, the approach with storing ID will work as well.

Regarding zombie jobs — IMHO it shouldn't be a big problem. Your server doesn't crash regularly, does it? In case of any problems you can always clear things in the web GUI or console.

Comment: The problem with zombie jobs is that if some process dies without me knowing about it the syncrhonization for this particular account won't happen anymore until I find out about this and delete the zombie. Sadly, uniqueness is what will cause this problem:) Not sure we wanna monitor them everyday or recieve angry mails from our customers

Comment: @Nondv so is a process dying or a server? Those are kind of different things

Sidekiq has a retry policy for failed jobs. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#best-practices

Comment: it's a worker dying during job processing. So the job gets locked but never unlocked

Comment: @Nondv for Sidekiq Pro there's a `super_fetch` strategy that will handle your case
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Reliability#using-super_fetch

It's paid, but if you're running an application that has to be very reliable it should worth it

Comment: @Nondv BTW with Sidekiq the situation you described won't happen. There will be a bit different problem. If the worker dies unexpectedly — the job will be lost. So it won't be a zombie and in your case shouldn't be a big problem I guess. Here's a good explanation about `basic_fetch` and `super_fetch` https://blog.bigbinary.com/2018/05/08/increase-reliability-of-background-job-processing-using-super_fetch-of-sidekiq-pro.html

Answer (score 2):

First things first, you are speeding the process up using **asynchronism**, not **parallelism**, subtle difference. :)

Secondly, it sounds like there are three main problems you want to solve:

1. Queue a job for each account.
2. Ensure at most only one unique job is ever queued.
3. Try to avoid long-living jobs.

Historically I've used Resque for this sort of thing - but I'm sure there are many alternatives.

You would do something like:

```
accounts.each { |a| Resque.enqueue(SyncAccount, a) }
```

To ensure they run at some point in the future, you could look at using **cron**, or **resque scheduler**.

As far as ensuring uniqueness of jobs, you could use some sort of caching layer like **Redis**, on which you store the output of a **hashing function** which takes in some arguments associated with the account that you use to create the jobs, which you query for prior to queueing a job, and write to redis after completing a job.

In order to avoid Zombie Jobs, most I'd recommend wrapping your job logic in reasonable **timeout blocks**, and yes, use some sort of cleaner to **prune dead jobs** off the queue.

Comment: we are gonna use multiple servers for this. Parallelism, isnt it?

Comment: @Nondv it's ever so slightly different, and often conflated. I'll refer you to a quora answer which quite nicely explains the difference with images: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-parallel-concurrent-and-asynchronous-programming

Comment: This is exactly how I understand the difference between them. Thanks for the link anyway:)

And for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see.

- Delayed Job or Sidekiq : It depends on the nature of your application. Since you already have a backend system for job queuing in place , you can very well use it. There are differences (positives and negatives) in every system , so it finally depends on your choice. To give you an example , if you're application is very database intensive, then it's generally good to avoid delayed_jobs.
- One DJ per account case : I'd do this.

i) Add a column to your accounts table. Say 'sync_status' . Before you queue a sync job , make the status as 'in_progress'.

ii) After that, write a custom job for syncing. It shouldn't be hard since you already have the business logic code in place. After the syncing is done, you can change the status to 'done' or back to 'ready'.

iii) This way, you can queue the job only if the 'sync_status' for that account is done/ready.

**Example:**

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(CustomSyncJob.new()) if account.ready_to_sync?
```

**Within custom_sync.rb, at the end:**

```
account.status = 'ready'
account.save
```

- Handling signals: Your application should never be crashing and your code should ensure that. But to kill DJ gracefully, you can add the following setting :

  Delayed::Worker.raise_signal_exceptions = :term

It will raise a SignalException. DJ will handle this gracefully by clearing the locked_by column.

Hope this helps. Cheers.